# AnguarJS and MongDB (CRUD) Save/Update -- Not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb

I have a form that is repeating data from mongoDB:

- Each data returns in a row - firstname, lastname and
  mobile
- User has 3 choices - edit, save and delete

Both edit and delete are working by pointing to the client._id. It is able to pick up the specific row but "save" is not working. I think there is a fundamental concept of ng-repeat and ng-click that I'm not understanding correctly

View

```
<form name="updateClientForm" ng-repeat="(clientIndex, client) in ctrl.clients" novalidate>

            <div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px">

                <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input name="firstname" class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="client.firstname" required>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input name="lastname" class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="client.lastname" required>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input name="mobile" class="form-control" minlength="8" maxlength="8" type="text" ng-model="client.mobile" required>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                        <button type="button" ng-click="ctrl.editClient(client._id)" class="btn-sm btn-warning">
                                <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </button>
                        <button name="button" ng-click="ctrl.saveClient(client)" class="btn-sm btn-success">
                                <i class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </button>
                            <button type="button" ng-click="ctrl.deleteClient(client._id); ctrl.removeRow(clientIndex);" class="btn-sm btn-danger">
                                <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </button>
                </div>

            </div>

        </form>
```

Controller

```
//SAVE
self.saveClient = function (client) {

  console.log("Saving client... ");
  console.log('client - before calling paAppAPI: ', client); //Returns array with client data

  paAppAPI.updateClient(client)
  .then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);

    self.message = result.data;
    self.showSuccessMessage = true;

  }).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
    self.message = err.data;
    self.showFailureMessage = true;
  });

}
```

Service

```
//SAVE
     self.updateClient = function (client) {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        const id = client._id; //ADDED

     console.log('client - before calling http: ', client); 
     console.log('id- before calling http: ', id); 

        $http.put("/api/client/" + id, {client : client})
            .then(function (result) {
                //alert(result.data.msg);
                console.log(client);
                defer.resolve(result);

            }).catch(function (err) {
                defer.reject(err);
            });

        return defer.promise;

    }
```

Routes

```
//SAVE
app.put("/api/client/:id", function (req, res) {

console.log(req.params.id); //returns correct id 
console.log(req.body.client); //returns newly edited data

    Client.updateOne({ "id" : req.params.id }, { $set: req.body.client }, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            handleError(err, res);
            return;
        }

        res.status(200).json({msg: 'Successfully saved'});
    });
});
```

Any advice would be helpful! :)

Comment: What made you think that `save` is not working?  Is the server api not getting called?  In the controller,  in `self.saveClient`, before calling the service `paAppAPI.updateClient`, can you place this `console.log(self.client)` and check the console to see what it prints.

Comment: console.log(self.client) returns Object
config
:
data
:
client
:
{}
__proto__
:
Object
headers
:
{Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*", Content-Type: "application/json;charset=utf-8"}
jsonpCallbackParam
:
"callback"
method
:
"PUT"
paramSerializer
:
ƒ ngParamSerializer(params)
transformRequest
:
[ƒ]
transformResponse
:
[ƒ]
url
:
"/api/client/undefined"
__proto__
:
Object
data
:
"id should be a (positive) number"
headers
:
ƒ (name)
status
:
400
statusText
:
"Bad Request"
xhrStatus
:
"complete"
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: When I click "save" it returns ... api/client/undefined Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400. Yes also server api is not called at all because without client._id it's somehow unable to understand that this is specific item is being saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form, make the following change - pass the `client` to `ctrl.saveClient`
`<button name="button" ng-click="ctrl.saveClient(client)" class="btn-sm btn-success">
                                <i class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>`

In Controller, make the following changes in self.saveClient

```
//SAVE
self.saveClient = function (client) {

  console.log("Saving client... ");
  console.log('client - before calling paAppAPI: ', client);
  paAppAPI.updateClient(client)
  .then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);

    self.message = result.data;
    self.showSuccessMessage = true;

  }).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
    self.message = err.data;
    self.showFailureMessage = true;
  });

}
```

In Service, make the following change in `self.updateClient`

```
//SAVE
    self.updateClient = function (client) {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        const id = client._id;
        console.log('client - before calling http: ', client);  
        console.log('id- before calling http: ', id);
        $http.put("/api/client/" + id, {client: client })
            .then(function (result) {
                console.log(result);
                defer.resolve(result);

            }).catch(function (err) {
                defer.reject(err);
            });

        return defer.promise;

    }
```

On the server, change the api for update as following

```
//SAVE
app.put("/api/client/:id", function (req, res) {

console.log(req.params.id); //returns undefined
console.log(req.body.client); //returns {}

    Client.updateOne({ "_id" : req.params.id }, { $set: req.body.client }, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            handleError(err, res);
            return;
        }

        res.status(200).json({msg: 'Successfully saved'});
    });
});
```

Comment: I just tried, this is the error on console: **PUT http://localhost:8080/api/client/undefined 400 (Bad Request)**. I tried both paAppAPI.updateClient(client) and paAppAPI.updateClient(self.client)

Comment: I have edited my answer. A change in the Service `self.updateClient` .

Comment: There is progress! No more errors in client side but no data is saved, "/api/client/undefined" because client returns empty. I console.log in routes to see what has been captured, on terminal  console.log(req.params.id); -- undefined
console.log(req.body.client); -- {}.

Comment: I have added some more console.log statements in the code. Can you report what it prints in the  console?

Comment: I was wrong. Client has value in controller but not in service. These 2 returns the same results -- client - before calling paAppAPI: ', client {_id: "5a12d64c1fcd9ba640788075", mobile: "12345678", lastname: "Doe", firstname: "Emily", __v: 0, …}; -- client - before calling http:  {_id: "5a12d64c1fcd9ba640788075", mobile: "12345678", lastname: "Doe", firstname: "Emily", __v: 0, …}; This console.log('id- before calling http: ', id); is ReferenceError: id is not defined

Comment: Can you ensure, in your code,  that `const id = client._id;` statement is there in your service, before the http call - `$http.put("/api/client/" + id, {client: client })`

Comment: Yes it has been added. I updated my codes for controller, service and routes in the question (removing edit and delete)

Comment: Sorry I realized I placed it wrongly! Here again: //////// client - before calling paAppAPI:  Object$$hashKey: "object:7"firstname: "Emily"lastname: "Doe"mobile: "12345678"__v: 0_id: "5a12d64c1fcd9ba640788075"__proto__: Object ///////client - before calling http:  Object__proto__: Object /////// id- before calling http:  undefined

Comment: In your controller, call the service as `paAppAPI.updateClient(client)`  - It seems you are still calling it as `paAppAPI.updateClient(self.client)`

Comment: ALL console messages are CORRECT! :) But... data is not saved in Mongo =.=. Mongo is connected and working, I just added new client and I can delete successfully

Comment: when you call the update api, what is returned from the server? Does the server return 'Successfully saved' message?  Or does the server log an error?  How you are checking whether an Item is updated/deleted in the server?

Comment: Not sure this will help, in the server route for update, use "_id" instead "id" - `Client.updateOne({ "_id" : req.params.id }, { $set: req.body.client }`

Comment: WOW you're right! That is the problem! THANK YOU SO MUCH for your patience

Comment: I have updated the answer with this. If it answers your question, please accept it. You may have to check your delete api also. It may not be deleting from  client from the db.

Comment: Thank you again :)